# next-auth doesn't reinitiate the unauthorized request after token expiry

Tags: next.js, access-token, next-auth, refresh-token, credential-providers

Once the token is expired it refresh successfully but next-auth doesn't re-initiate the last request so:

- next-auth redirects me to /sign-in page.
- GET request which caused the 401 keeps responding "UnAuthorized".
- logging the accessToken shows that it has been refreshed and the
  session is updated.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import { postRequest } from "../api_requests"
import { settings } from "app.config"
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode"


const refreshAccessToken = async (token) => {
    const newAccessToken = await postRequest(
        `/auth/refresh`,
        { refreshToken: token.user.refreshToken },
        token.user.refreshToken
    )

    const newToken = (newAccessToken.data) ? newAccessToken.data : { error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" }
    return newToken
}

const providers = [
    CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
            username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "username ..." },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            const { username, password } = credentials
            const { statusCode, data: user } = await postRequest('/auth/signin', {
                user: username,
                password
            })

            if (user && (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201)) {
                return user
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
    })
]


const callbacks = {
    jwt: async ({ token, user, account, trigger, session }) => {

        // if user --> set token.user
        user && (token.user = user)

        // session update -- clientAPI -- User_Profile update
        if (trigger === "update") {
            return { ...token, user: session.user }
        }


        // ===== EXPIRY ===== // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        // if token expired --> refreshToken
        const { exp } = jwtDecode(token?.user?.accessToken)
        const shouldRefreshTime = Math.round((exp * 1000) - Date.now())
        console.log({ shouldRefreshTime })

        // accessToken expired
        if (shouldRefreshTime <= 0) {
            // refresh -then-> update token.user
            const newToken = await refreshAccessToken(token)
            console.log({ newToken })
            token.user = {
                ...token.user,
                ...newToken
            }
        }

        // If the token is still valid, just return it.
        return token
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        session && (session.user = token.user)  // Setting token in session
        return session;
    },
}

export const authOptions = {
    secret: settings.env.nextAuthSecret,
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers,
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: "/authentication/sign-in"
    },
    callbacks,
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I need to make it reinitiate the request which caused the 401 regarding to the token has expired.
I don't want to check token expiry on every single response, so I'm trying to manage refreshing the accessToken globally.